# Where is mysql's configuration file in ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

I recently installed MySql Server 8.0.19 on and EC2 (t2.micro) instance running Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to find the MySql configuration file that's like the `my.ini` on Windows.

I've looked through almost every file in `/etc/mysql/` but none of them are similar to the `my.ini` that windows uses. Where is this file located on Ubuntu 18.04 and where are the configuration settings read from?

Comment: So , where are the default values stored and read from? Like port, bind-address etc.

Comment: @singrium he is asking about an EC instance. Those use a different method :)

Comment: @Rinzwind, sorry I didn't notice that. Thank you for the correction :) and thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Do an update of the locate database and search for my.cnf

```
sudo locatedb
locate my.cnf
```

The 2 likely places are

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/home/$USER/.my.cnf
```

That is the GENERIC method of finding files on a server.

But ...

> EC2 instance

That does not use a generic configuration. The name depends on the type of instance: `my-small.cnf`, `my-medium.cnf`, `my-large.cnf`. Use that for the `locate`.

Mind also that EC settings often need to be done from within the console and not on command line!

Comment: I've looked through /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which finally points to /var/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf which only has `[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log` So where is it getting the values for long_query_time etc?

Comment: You did not find one of my-small.cnf, my-medium.cnf, my-large.cnf? Please edit the question to include what the type is of the instance. I would start with the EC2 console; that is where I mosttimes see these things happen. It is totally possible that this is done in memory and not on-disk.  (we have EC2 instances and have a `my-large.cnf` but the file is in a virtual directory).

Comment: Instance type is t2.micro

Answer (score 1):

The default location should be /etc/mysql

Try searching for my.cnf
find -name my.cnf or locate my.cnf from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found it here:

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

There was nothing inside, but when I changed and restarted MySQL it did take effect

I am on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 22.04 I found it here:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```